# com.google.android.feedback in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

In Google Analytics I see `com.google.android.feedback` and `com.android.vending` under Acquisitions tab.

I know that `com.android.vending` is referring to installation from Google Play.

But what is `com.google.android.feedback` referring to?

Comment: You can find some information in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14178261/787375) answer. Moreover, searching at google I only found [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yqZNzK8Q), seems like `com.google.android.feedback` package comes from `GoogleFeedBack.apk`. The APK is included in various Android ROMS, [here](https://github.com/greenromproject/android_vendor_greenromproject/blob/master/proprietary/GoogleFeedback.apk) or [here](https://github.com/Tragidy/LightELF/blob/master/system/app/GoogleFeedback.apk). Google results points out that maybe this APK is included in some versions of Cyano

Comment: I compared count of com.google.android.feedback in Google Analytics to count of CRASHES & ANRS in Google Paly Developer Console and found these to be equal. So I guess com.google.android.feedback is referring to app crash info sent by users.